# gcc -pg creates a.out instead of gmon.out

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

How can I make my gcc -pg create a gmon.out file instead of an a.out? I'm trying to profile my CPU using gprof, but when I compile my .c file I get an a.out, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The profile is generated when you run the compiled program, not upon compilation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gcc -pg yourfile.c #compile with -pg

$ ./a.out #execute it
```

Now, you can see the `gmon.out` file.